# How to query asynchronously using arrow adbc connector in python?

Tags: python, fastapi, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am connecting to a postgres db using apache-arrow ADBC driver. The goal is to fetch arrow tables from the postgres.

```
conn = adbc_driver_postgresql.dbapi.connect(database_url)
```

the below code i want to put in a async method in fastapi endpoint. But it seems the cursor is not awaitable. How can I make the queries asynchronous

```
with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("SELECT * from segments")
    data = cur.fetch_arrow_table()
```

Comment: As far as I know the Apache Arrow ADBC Python library is not async compatible.